# Blender Python Custom Render Engine Settings

Tags: python, render, blender

I'm trying to make a custom game engine in Blender using Python. I got it in and everything but I want to set the render settings so that I can set it as a game engine and not a render engine.

In the documentation, I found the `RenderSettings` struct class and I have no idea how to use it in anything. I created my render engine inheriting the `RenderEngine` class already but have no idea how to use the `RenderSettings` class.

The reason I need the `RenderSettings` class is that I need to access the property `use_game_engine` and set it to `True` so that Blender will show game properties and not render properties. I've been trying to figure this out for hours now and have tried everything I can think of. I don't know if I'm just stupid or if I'm missing something or what... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Documentation Links:
http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.RenderEngine.html

http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_73_release/bpy.types.RenderSettings.html

Comment: You can get blender specific help at [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

An instance of the RenderSettings class can be found in the scene data block as the `render` property. So the `use_game_engine` for the current scene can be found at -

```
bpy.context.scene.render.use_game_engine
```

If you have multiple scenes you can also access each scene through -

```
bpy.data.scenes['MyScene'].render.use_game_engine
```